# Can you use a silver coin as an improvised melee weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, improvised-weaponry, special-materials

Super cool warblade fighting a vampire. Alas, he has no silver weapons. Can I hold a silver coin in my fingers and rake at him or in between my knuckles and punch at him?

I saw a similar 5e answer but nothing for 3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warblade's attacks with that silver coin will bypass the vampire's [damage reduction](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#damage-reduction) if the DM rules that a lone silver coin can be used as an [improvised weapon](http://dndsrd.net/weapons.html#improvised-weapons).

*Complete Warrior* expands the rules for improvised weapons, and it says that any improvised weapon weighing less than 2 lbs. deals 1d3 points of damage. Nonetheless, this player wouldn't be surprised by a DM ruling that an item weighing 1/50 lb.—like a silver piece—deals less than 1d3 points of damage.

Note that while the name of the special material [**alchemical silver**](http://dndsrd.net/specialMaterials.html#silver-alchemical) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 284—5) seems to imply that it's somehow different from normal silver, it's really the process of binding the silver to the weapon that gives the material the adjective *alchemical*; the silver itself remains just silver.